# html syntax in templates playframework

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I created a new controller in Play! framework. I want to put a static text into Scala template, but I am getting `<br />` (all html syntax) rendered as a text. How I can do that?

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        String page_content = "<strong>Lorem </strong>Ipsum is simply dummy text of the<br /> printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
        return ok(views.html.index.render(page_content, "index"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `index` is passing two `Strings` to your view function:

```
public static Result index() {
    String page_content = "<strong>Lorem </strong>Ipsum is simply dummy text of the<br /> printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
    return ok(views.html.index.render(page_content, "index"));
}
```

So your template should be something like:

```
@(controllerHtml: String, title: String)
@main(title) {
 @Html(controllerHTML)
}
```

Remember that:
*By default, dynamic content parts are escaped according to the template type’s (e.g. HTML or XML) rules. If you want to output a raw content fragment, wrap it in the template content type.* See the documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTemplates

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to write content of pages in Play! framework. For HTML rendering the templates are the best (at least for those who've just started using the framework).

For start I would direct you to do the tutorial for [Java](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList) or [Scala](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTodoList). Repeating all documentation here is pointless.

On the other hand if you really insist to put hard-coded text on your page it is enough to pass is as an argument to the `ok` response, but you cannot omit the whole HTML boiler plate. Here is Scala code:

```
def index = Action {
  val pageContent = 
    <html> 
      <body>
        <strong>Lorem </strong>Ipsum is simply dummy text of the<br /> printing and typesetting industry.
      </body>
    <html>;
   Ok(pageContent)
}
```